# Multiple cites with parenthesis around the entire multicite

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to achieve a result, which is the equivalent of \cites, with potentially references for all the cites. My citation is inline with text and I'd like to have it surrounded by parenthesis.

I've found the following references, eg [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142804/placing-brackets-only-when-citing-multiple-sources) is about putting brackets only if there is more than one cite or [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/multiple-citations-with-pages-using-biblatex) is about multiple citations using the `\cites(<multipre>)(<multipost>)`.

However, I cannot find a way to mix both of them. My target are :

- Parenthesis around the entire block (**missing**)
- No point at the end (done)
- Title is emphasized, name are in small caps (done)
- French as main language (done)

Here is what I've achieved so far with my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{PsammetichusII.bib}
@article{Gozzoli1,
author = {Gozzoli, Roberto B.},
title = {The Statue BM EA 37891 and the Erasures of Necho II's Names},
}
@book{Gozzoli2,
author = {Gozzoli, Roberto B.},
title = {The Writing of History in Ancient Egypt during the First Millennium BC (ca. 1070-180 BC). Trends and Perspectives},
shorttitle = {The Writing of History},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber,language=french]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{PsammetichusII.bib}

\UndefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\newcommand{\no}{n\textsuperscript{o}\space}
\newcommand{\nos}{n\textsuperscript{os}\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\ucites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{document}
a first test as demo \ucites[1]{Gozzoli1}[4]{Gozzoli2}

a second text which also has some references \ucites[\nos 1, 2, 5]{Gozzoli1}[10, 11]{Gozzoli2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional *wrapper* argument to `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand` looks as if it could be what you are looking for

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\ucites}[\mkbibparens]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}
```

In total

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Gozzoli1,
author = {Gozzoli, Roberto B.},
title = {The Statue BM EA 37891 and the Erasures of Necho II's Names},
}
@book{Gozzoli2,
author = {Gozzoli, Roberto B.},
title = {The Writing of History in Ancient Egypt during the First Millennium BC (ca. 1070-180 BC). Trends and Perspectives},
shorttitle = {The Writing of History},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber,language=french]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\UndefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\newcommand{\no}{n\textsuperscript{o}\space}
\newcommand{\nos}{n\textsuperscript{os}\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\ucites}[\mkbibparens]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{document}
a first test as demo \ucites[1]{Gozzoli1}[4]{Gozzoli2}

a second text which also has some references \ucites[\nos 1, 2, 5]{Gozzoli1}[10, 11]{Gozzoli2}
\end{document}
```

[image: the citations are surrounded by round brackets]

Comment: Perfect ! should have tried that by myself, the *wrapper* term make sense now.

Comment: @XaWin At least in the example your `\ucites` is actually more or less `\parencites`. If you do not intend to use both `\ucites` and `\parencites` with different behaviour in your actual document, I suggest you use `\parencites` since that is the canonical name for such a command.

Comment: You're right, the behavior is the same. I went with a simpler `\newcommand{\ucites}{\parencites}`. My project is template-based so it's easier for me to have a set of "u-command" and compiling. This way I'm more flexible if suddenly the parenthesis needs to be bracket : I won't need to redefine the parencites, but just redefine my `\ucites`